How to convert in iOS a RealityKit SpatialTapGesture value to an Entity coordinate?
I have an app with a visionOS target, and I want to add an iOS target. Both are based on RealityKit.
I want to use a SpatialTapGesture to get the tap coordinate local to the entity tapped.
In visionOS this is easy:
SpatialTapGesture(coordinateSpace: .local)
    .targetedToAnyEntity()
    .onEnded { tap in
        let entity = tap.entity
        // Converts from the local space of the View this gesture is attached to the local coordinate space of the Entity that was tapped.
        let localPoint3D = tap.convert(tap.location3D, from: .local, to: entity)
        // …
    }

However, according to the docs, the convert function seems to exist only in visionOS, not in iOS.
So how can I do this conversion in iOS?
EDIT:
Since function convert does not (yet) exist in iOS, I tried to find a workaround.
One can in some cases potentially use the following function of RealityViewCameraContent:
func unproject(
    _ point: CGPoint,
    from space: some CoordinateSpaceProtocol,
    to realitySpace: some RealityCoordinateSpace,
    ontoPlane: float4x4
) -> SIMD3<Float>?  

The docu says:

A 2D point in the view’s coordinate space can refer to any point along
a line segment in the 3D coordinate space. Unprojecting gets the 3D
position of the point along this line segment that intersects the
provided plane.

My app requires to get the tapped 3D position on top of a board entity, e.g. a plane.
I thus tried to use unproject by passing in a plane that is parallel to the top of my board.
Here is my code. I am saving first the RealityViewCameraContent in the RealityView's update function:
@State private var savedContent: RealityViewCameraContent?  

The SpatialTapGesture I am using is:
SpatialTapGesture(coordinateSpace: .local)
    .targetedToAnyEntity()
    .onEnded { tap in
        // Create the 4x4 matrix representing the plane
        var planeMatrix = matrix_identity_float4x4
        planeMatrix.columns.0 = SIMD4<Float>(1, 0, 0, 0) // x-axis
        planeMatrix.columns.1 = SIMD4<Float>(0, 1, 0, 0) // y-axis (normal)
        planeMatrix.columns.2 = SIMD4<Float>(0, 0, 1, 0) // z-axis
        planeMatrix.columns.3 = SIMD4<Float>(0, 0, -3.4, 1) // Translation              

        guard let localPoint3D = savedContent?.unproject(tap.location,
                                                         from: .global,
                                                         to: .camera,
                                                         ontoPlane: planeMatrix) else {
            return
        }
        print(localPoint3D)
    }  

My first observation is that parameter from has 2 options: .global and .local, and parameter to has also 2 options: .scene and .camera.
If I set to to .scene, the function always returns nil, probably because I have a non-AR app. If I set to to .camera, I get a point in 3D space, and this point depends on where I tap the screen. However, the coordinate values are always extremely small, something like 1.0e-7, and I don't understand why. Setting from to .global and .local does not make much difference.
Has anybody tried to unproject a screen coordinate? Is something wrong with my code?
